# Why Operator Methods Should Be Static In C#?

Tags: c#, static, overloading, operator-keyword

Why in C# we use static with operator methods?

I have tried reading different articles on internet but they didn't help me in answering it.

```
public static int operator+(int I, Complex C) 
{ 
    return C.x + I;
}
```

Also when i try to do c+2 it works fine but when i do 2+c it gives me an error because i am not having an extra overloaded function for this call match of parameters. Is there any way by which i can run both statements like c+2 and 2+c with a single overloaded operator definition of function?

Answer (score 1):

The specification has the following to say about user-defined operators (emphasis mine)

> The following rules apply to all operator declarations:
>
> •**An operator declaration shall include both a public and a static modifier**.
>
> •The parameter(s) of an operator shall have no modifiers.
>
> •The signature of an operator (§15.10.2, §15.10.3, §15.10.4) shall differ from the signatures of all other operators declared in the same class.
>
> •All types referenced in an operator declaration shall be at least as accessible as the operator itself (§8.5.5).
>
> •It is an error for the same modifier to appear multiple times in an operator declaration.

"Because the spec says so" might not be the most satisfying answer, but it's the best I have. I'm guessing that virtual dispatch doesn't make much sense for operators.

As for your second question, my approach would be to implement a private static method that does your operation, and then have two operator implementations point to it.

Something like this:

```
public static int operator+(int i, Complex c) => AddInt(c, i); 

public static int operator+(Complex c, int i) => AddInt(c, i); 

private static int AddInt(Complex c, int i) => c.X + i;
```

Comment: my question is why operator methods should be defined with static keyword? and why i have to overload 2 different versions of my operator functions to add things like these c+2 , 2+c ? is there any way that can freed me from arguments order?